Silent exit when loading via FluxTransformer2DModel.from_single_file and no GPU use
I'm using the following test code, but when running the FluxTransformer2DModel.from_single_file it's just consume around 15GB of RAM (I still have around 7GB of RAM free), not using the GPU (4070TI with 12GB VRAM) and just silently exit at the loading transformer block, after a 1-2 minutes and back to the terminal, without any error.
I have tried several configurations, which didn't worked for me.
I don't have any issue with the GPU nor CUDA version using torch - if I'm running only the FluxPipeline.from_pretrained I can see the VRAM is maxed out until the model is running out of memory.
I'm running this using a vscode devcontainer (nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:24.08-py3) where the host machine is Windows 11 with i713700/32GB.
transformer = FluxTransformer2DModel.from_single_file(
    "./flux-text-to-image/flux-fp8/flux1-dev-fp8.safetensors",
    torch_dtype=dtype,
    use_safetensors=True,
    local_files_only=False,
    variant="fp16" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "fp32",
    device_map="auto",  # This should handle multi-GPU setups or fallback to CPU if needed,
    offload_folder="./offload",  # Save parts of the model to disk if needed
)

pipe = FluxPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "./flux-text-to-image/FLUX.1-dev",
    transformer=transformer,
    local_files_only=False,
    device_map="auto",  # This should handle multi-GPU setups or fallback to CPU if needed
    torch_dtype=dtype,
)

Would love to get inputs on what I am missing here.
Notes:

CUDA available: True
CUDA version: 12.6
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070Ti 12GB
Using device: cuda
Using dtype: torch.float16

